# Why is my texture not showing correctly?

Tags: texturing

I am still learning blender and I followed a tutorial that adds textures. I followed it step by step but my texture just won't show correctly.

Am I missing something super obvious?

[image: screenshot]

https://ibb.co/9grsrzg

Comment: Are the meshes UV mapped?  That may be the super obvious thing getting missed.

Comment: Have you applied the scale to your objects? Also read up on unwrapping UVs.

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: open the UV Editor and select a whole mesh in Edit mode in order to see the UVs

Comment: Check that you are showing the render view not the lookldev view, try cycles renderer.  As others have suggested, Object -> Apply all Transformations, redo the UV Map and scale it in the UV editor.  Also enable 'Face Orientation' in the Viewport Overlays to make sure your 'floor' is blue not red.  If it is red, flip the normals on that object.

Comment: @JannisN Please do not link external images but use the image upload function of BSE and add them directly to your question.

Comment: My guess is that if you don't know how to check the UV map, then you most certainly did not unwrap. For a start, select the whole object in edit mode, press U (unwrap) and select "cube projection". This is not a perfect method, but it will at least let you see your textures, and you will actually have some shapes on your UV map to play with. For a more in depth (and I mean _really_ in depth) description of UV's and how they are used, see here. It's long, but complete - https://artisticrender.com/the-definitive-tutorial-to-uv-mapping-in-blender/